# linking and compiling with Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
GNU Make 3.82
```

I am trying compile this program I have using this Makefile. I have only 1 src file at the moment, but I will have more later to include.

I am trying to get the Makefile to create the bin directory if it doesn't exist and put the binary executable in there.

```
INC_PATH=-I/home/dev_tools/apr/include/apr-1
LIB_PATH=-L/home/dev_tools/apr/lib
LIBS=-lapr-1
RUNTIME_PATH=/home/dev_tools/apr/lib
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -g -m32 -D_DEBUG -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -O2 $(INC_PATH)
OBJECTS=timeout.o
EXECUTABLE=bin/to

all:    build $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE):
    $(CC) -m32 -o $@ -Wl,-rpath,$(RUNTIME_PATH), $(LIB_PATH) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

build:
    @mkdir -p bin

clean:
    rm -rf *~ timeout *.o
```

I am getting this error:

```
make
gcc -m32 -o bin/to -Wl,-rpath,/home/dev_tools/apr/lib, -L/home/dev_tools/apr/lib timeout.o -lapr-1
gcc: error: timeout.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [bin/to] Error 1
```

When I remove the `$(OBJECTS)` I get the following:

```
gcc -m32 -o bin/to -Wl,-rpath,/home/dev_tools/apr/lib, -L/home/dev_tools/apr/lib -lapr-1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/to] Error 1
```

Not sure where I am going wrong with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified how to build the target timeout.o.

You need to add the following code:

```
timeout.o: timeout.c
            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

If you end up with more source file that you need compiled, you can use a pattern matching rule like this:

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 2):

Makefiles can be a bit tricky.  Because you want to continue adding more objects to your `OBJECT` variable, I would actually add a prerequisite to `EXECUTABLE` to make sure all of your objects are compiled.  From there, the automatic rule inference should take care of the rest.

Basically replace the line with:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) -m32 -o $@ -Wl,-rpath,$(RUNTIME_PATH), $(LIB_PATH) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its showing error because make is not able to find timeout.o file in the current directory.
If you have timeout.c file then add the following to your makefile

`OBJECTS: timeout.c`

```
      $(CC) -c timeout.c
```